# Strange behaviour when using NOT LIKE in simple SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-like

I don't fully understand why I'm getting strange SQL statement results with the following statement:

When I don't filter my statement I get ~480 results. When I filter my statement with `and table.person like '%blablabla%'` I get ~20 results. When I filter my statement with `and not table.person like '%blablabla%'` I get ~420 results.

I don't get where the other 40 results disappear to just by reversing the results.

No difference if I use `not like` instead of `and not`

```
SELECT person.B2 as name, person.B1 as surname, person.ID as loginname, ksdef.short as actualcourse
FROM person, user, ksdef
WHERE person.ID = user.personID AND user.ksdefID = ksdef.ID
AND person.FID = 0 
AND ksdef.short like '%EA%' 
AND ksdef.first> '2017-08-01' 
AND person.comment not like '%leiche%'
Order By ksdef.first, ksdef.short desc;
```

Comment: It is likely that `person` is null in some rows. NULL is neither LIKE something nor unLIKE someting.

Comment: ah.. thanks... I guess I remember I heard that before :)

Comment: As to `some lectures in university`: And they taught you the 1980's join syntax? I can hardly believe that. Explicit joins like `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc. were introduced in the SQL standard in 1992!

Comment: we learned both but somehow I find the where syntax easier and I'm just lazy xD
while we're still at it... how to form the statement to get alle without '%leiche%' and with NULL? thanks in advance >_<

Comment: nevermind... got it... it's not "= NULL" and instead "is NULL".. just remembered I had that too...

Comment: I've posted an answer. It is recommended, by the way, to tag SQL questions with the DBMS used, as answers may vary depending on the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Its Better to use Joins for such queries.

```
SELECT p.B2 as name, p.B1 as surname, p.ID as loginname, k.short as actualcourse
FROM person p
Inner Join user u on p.ID = u.personID
Inner Join ksdef k on u.ksdefID = k.ID AND k.short like '%EA%' AND k.first> '2017-08-01' 
Where p.FID = 0 
AND ( p.comment NOT LIKE '%leiche%' OR p.comment is NULL)
Order By k.first, k.short desc;
```

Comment: That is correct, but it doesn't answer the question :-)

Comment: Updated the code to get all without '%leiche%' and with NULL

Comment: thanks anyway :) shame on me for being lazy though... :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with null. In some rows `comment` is null.

```
AND person.comment LIKE '%leiche%'
```

gets all strings that are definitely matching '%leiche%'. As NULL represents the "unknown value", it doesn't return rows where comment is null.

```
AND person.comment NOT LIKE '%leiche%'
```

gets all strings that are definitely different from '%leiche%'. As NULL represents the "unknown value", again it doesn't return rows where comment is null.

To get nulls, too, include that in your conditions:

```
AND (person.comment LIKE '%leiche%' OR person.comment IS NULL)
```

or

```
AND (person.comment NOT LIKE '%leiche%' OR person.comment IS NULL)
```